# Updating parent entity with children that already exist EF

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework

I have a model which consists of movies and actors, currently to update already existing movie (that is fill it with information and actors which star in it) I use this

```
    public void Update(Movie item)
    {
        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

But how do I make it so that if I add a movie which has actors that are already in DB, those are not added again and simply ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a `Movie` class and an `Actor` class with a many-to-many relationship:
A movie can have many actors and an actor can appear in many movies.

[See this link to see how the many-to-many is configured](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

If you configure the many-to-many correctly you won't have to worry that existing actors are added again if he appears in a new movie.

The following code will illustrate this:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actors {get; set;}

}

public class Actor
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies {get; set;}
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Actor> Actors {get; set;}
}

public void Test()
{
    // create some actors
    var actor1 = new Actor() { Name = "Actor 1"}
    var actor2 = new Actor() { Name = "Actor 2" };
    var actor3 = new Actor() { Name = "Actor 3" };

    // add a movie with some of these actors
    var movieToAdd = new Movie()
    {
        Title = "Hello Dolly",
        Actors = new List<Actor>() {actor1, actor2},
    };
    var addedMovie = dbContext.Movies.Add(movieToAdd);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    // add another movie, with one existing actor and one not-existing actor
    var otherMovieToAdd = new Movie()
    {
        Title = "Dracula",
        Actors = new List<Actor>(){actor3, actor2},
    };
    var otherAddedMovie = dbContext.Movies.Add(otherMovieToAdd);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    // check the existing actors
    foreach (var actorName in dbContext.Actors.Select(actor => actor.Name))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(actorName);
    }
}
```

The output will be

```
Actor 1
Actor 2
Actor 3
```

Note, that although you didn't add any Actor specifically, they were added, because the movie in which they appeared were added. Any existing actor(one with an Id unequal to zero) are not added again.

So the answer to your question: if you configure the many-to-many relation correctly, you won't have to worry that existing actors are added twice.